# Batch file convert to Linux script

Tags: linux, cmd

due to migrating of batch job to Linux server I have problem finding the equivalent of the following commands in Linux:

**Y drive** is a map drive to the NAS drive which is also connected to Ubuntu server /NAS/CCTV . Need to search every sub folders for all .264 files

**Z drive** is on the Ubuntu server itself. Just move every .mp4 files here, no folder here. Path on Ubuntu is /Share/CCTV/

Its just a simple script to convert the cctv capture .264 format to mp4 and move to server to be process and delete off any h264 files and any folder thats older than 1 day, the script will schedule to run every 3 mins.

I have ffmpeg installed on the Ubuntu server, just unable to find the for each file in the folders to do the same.

Also for the last for files command that delete folder older than 1 days

```
FOR /r y:\ %%F in (*.h264) do c:\scripts\ffmpeg -i %%F %%F.mp4

FOR /r y:\ %%F in (*.h264) do del %%F

FOR /r y:\ %%G in (*.mp4) do move %%G Z:\

forfiles -p "Y:\" -d -1 -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
```

Appreciate any forms of help or point me to the right guide so I can rewrite it on the Linux server. I did try to search for for loop but all show me to count number, maybe I search wrongly.

Comment: I found something similar and modify a little to look like this, haven't test it yet. Please correct me if its wrong.


for i in *.h264; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Find all .h264 files (recursively)

```
find /NAS/CCTV -type f -name '*.h264'
```

## Convert all such files to .mp4

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r file ; do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" "$file".mp4
done < <(find /NAS/CCTV -type f -name '*.h264' -print0)
```

Note that this will create files called like `filename.h264.mp4`. This matches your batch file behavior. If you would prefer to replace the extension use `ffmpeg -i "$file" "${file%.*}".mp4` instead and you will get a name like `filename.h264`.

## Also move those mp4 files to another directory

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r file ; do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" "$file".mp4
    if [[ -f $file.mp4 ]] ; then
        mv -f -- "$file".mp4 /Share/CCTV
    fi
done < <(find /NAS/CCTV -type f -name '*.h264' -print0)
```

## Delete old directories (recursively)

```
find /NAS/CCTV -type d -not -newermt '1 day ago' -exec rm -rf {} +
```

## Documentation.

The `find` command recursively lists files according to criteria you specify. Any time you need to deal with files in multiple directories or very large numbers of files it is probably what you want to use. For safety against malicious file names it's important to `-print0` so file names are delimited by null rather than newline, which then requires using the `IFS= read -d ''` construct to interpret later.

The `while read variable ; do ... done` construct reads data from input and assigns each record to the named variable. This allows each matching file to be handled one at a time inside the loop. The insides of the loop should be fairly obvious.

Again `find` is used to select files, but in this case the files are directories. The switches `-not -newer` select files which are `not` `newer` (in other words, files which are older) according to their `m` time, the modification time, compared against `t`, which in this case means that the next argument is text describing a time. Here you can use any expression understood by GNU `date`'s `-d` switch, so I can write in plain English and it will work as expected.

As you embark on your shell scripting journey you should keep two things by your side:

- [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) - Always runs scripts you write through shellcheck to catch basic errors.
- [Bash FAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) - The bash FAQ at wooledge.org. Most of the answers to questions you have not thought of yet will be here. For example [FAQ 15](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/015) is highly relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in /NAS/CCTV/*.h264; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "$f".mp4; done
rm /NAS/CCTV/*.h264
mv /NAS/CCTV/*.mp4 /Share/CCTV
find /NAS/CCTV/ -type d -ctime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, the first line show no such file or directory, however if I change it to the actual path it able to find and convert to mp4 format, do I need any additional parameter so it can search sub sub directory or even more deeper directory? /NAS/CCTV/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3/.../ where subdirectories 2 and 3 is date and hour

Comment: `/NAS/CCTV/*.h264` areonly files in your current dir. For recursive searching you need to use find. See Sorpigal answer